# Laptop Only Accepting 3.0 USB

Tags: windows-10, drivers, port, usb-3

I have been using Dell Inspiron 7567 for the last 2 years. Suddenly a strange issue appeared. Now my laptop is only accepting 3.0 USB. No other than 3.0. Not even mouse. In the device manager, I am seeing a message Unknown USB device (Device Descriptor request failed). I tried reinstalling the windows 2 times and updating the bios but no luck.

Comment: I would boot a live Linux system from USB-stick or DVD and test if USB 2 devices work on Linux. If they don't work, too then it is a hardware defect. USB pre-3.0 and 3.0+ are processed internally by different components (the ports are dynamically routed to the matching component). May be in your laptop the USB 2.0 broke.

Comment: @Robert I never used Linux. I'll see if someone has another simpler method. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't need to know much about Linux, just download a live Linux system and write it to an USB stick (as e.g. described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started)) or DVD and boot from it and then check of USB 1.x/2.0 devices work.

Comment: Ok @Robert I'll give it a try. Thank you so much for this